# Start TableView at specific index path row

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a a `tableView` that I want to show on screen at a specific `indexPath.row`.

For example, say each `tableViewCell` takes up half of the screen, and I want the screen to appear at `indexPath.row` of 6, **instead of always starting at `indexPath.row` of 0**.

Is there any way to do this?

To make clearer, I want to have the table view appear scrolled such that rows 0-5 are scrolled off-screen, and row 6 is the top row in the table view.

Comment: It isn't clear what you mean. Are you saying that you want to have your table view appear scrolled such that rows 0-5 are scrolled off-screen, and row 6 is the top row in the table view?

Comment: Yeah that says it much better than I must have.  Thanks!  I'll update the Q

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use scrollToRowAtIndexPath:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:N inSection:M];
    [yourTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath 
                         atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop 
                                 animated:YES];
```

You can experiment with these positions until you are happy with the results

```
UITableViewScrollPositionNone
UITableViewScrollPositionTop
UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle
UITableViewScrollPositionBottom
```

Comment: To add a little more -- I would put this in either `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear:` to avoid any jerkiness after the view is already on screen.

Comment: But if you want the table view to start out in a scrolled position then you should pass `animated: NO`.

Answer (score 1):

In Swift you can use something like this:

```
func scrollToSelectedPosition() {
    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: selectedPositionInt!, inSection: 0)
    self.tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: .Top, animated: false)
}
```

Where selectedPositionInt is the position you want to scroll to.